# How to get the url and the title from the <a> tags with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm coding a script to get all the links from the divs with a class="pntc-txt" and after I want to get from the `<a>` tags the href attribute and also the text between the `<a href="">Something</a>`. For after take that url and text and insert them in a database. I'll post the code that I've done so far:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import *

sock = urllib.request.urlopen("http://as.com/tag/moto_gp/a/") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)


for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'pntc-txt'}):
    a = div.findAll('a')
    print (a)
```

Comment: It's fully documented here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *

srcCode = requests.get("http://as.com/tag/moto_gp/a/")
plainText = srcCode.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText)


for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'pntc-txt'}):
    for each in div.findAll('a'):      #get all elements with 'a' tag
        href = each.get('href')
        print href          #print href
        print each.string   #print the text in tags
        print each          #print whole tag
```

**Note:** also removed the urllib part to read the html page. Instead used package `requests`